# How to search ocurrence of a word and absence of another using grep

Tags: linux, command-line, search, grep

I have a file with content similar to:

```
google.com,9,AB+CD,nonAB+nonCD
youtube.com,9,AB+CD,AB+CD
facebook.com,20,AB+CD,nonCD
```

The number of columns is not fixed. But the first column is a URL, the second is a number, starting form the third is keywords separated by commas but they vary from site to another.

I want to count the number of URLs (lines) where I can control what keywords are in the line. For example,
1) `AB+CD` without `nonAB` and `nonCD`. Note: the word AB+CD can occur many times.
2) AB+CD without occurrence of `nonCD` (but it is ok if there is anything else)

How to search for a string in a line AND ensure the absence of another string. When I use:

```
grep 'AB+CD' test.txt > result.txt
```

It prints every line where 'AB+CD' is found.

What if I want to print the line where there is only 'AB+CD' to get:

```
youtube.com,9,AB+CD,AB+CD
```

Or there is 'AB+CD' with anything else except 'nonAB' to get:

```
youtube.com,9,AB+CD,AB+CD
facebook.com,20,AB+CD,nonCD
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just wanted a plain text search without caring about columns, you can chain the inverted match `grep -v` like so:

```
cat input.txt | grep 'IncludedText' | grep -v 'ExcludedText'
```

If you want to do proper filtering by column, you'd want to use something like `awk`.

Comment: Doesn't this usage of `cat` fall in the category of [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat) ? :p

Comment: @Zubzub I'd argue not - personally I like to use a separate `cat` when it's a longer pipeline, rather than have the unbalance of the first `grep` taking the file while the second `grep` does not.

Comment: Maybe `< input.txt grep 'IncludedText' | grep -v 'ExcludedText'` looks a little less unbalanced :-)

Answer (score 4):

General tricks:

1. Lines containing `foo` plus lines containing `bar` (`foo OR bar`):

   ```
   grep -e foo -e bar
   ```
2. Lines containing `foo` and `bar` in the same line (`foo AND bar`):

   ```
   grep foo | grep bar
   ```
3. Lines not containing `baz` (`NOT baz`):

   ```
   grep -v baz
   ```

With these bricks you can build your logic. The problem is `-v` is not restricted to a single pattern, it's global to entire `grep` (at least in my Debian). This makes `NOT (foo OR bar)` possible:

```
grep -v -e foo -e bar
```

which is equivalent to `(NOT foo) AND (NOT bar)`:

```
grep -v foo | grep -v bar
```

However `NOT (foo AND bar)` (logically equivalent to `(NOT foo) OR (NOT bar)`) is not that easy. We can try to obtain `foo AND bar` with a *single* (extended) `grep`:

2. Again lines containing `foo` and `bar` in the same line (`foo AND bar`):

   ```
   grep -E 'foo.*bar|bar.*foo'
   ```

Now to get `NOT (foo AND bar)`:

```
grep -v -E 'foo.*bar|bar.*foo'
```

---

I'm not sure if the above is a complete system when dealing with more than two patterns. Still few of your problems are solvable with it. Example:

> `AB+CD` without `nonAB` and `nonCD`

If I get you right it's `AB+CD AND NOT (nonAB OR nonCD)`

```
grep AB+CD | grep -v -e nonAB -e nonCD
```

---

Notice this request makes things complicated:

> I want to print the line where there is only 'AB+CD'

One may say `grep ,AB+CD,AB+CD` will do, but since "the number of columns is not fixed", I guess you'd like to tell apart these two lines:

```
youtube.com,9,AB+CD,AB+CD,AB+CD
youtube.com,9,AB+CD,AB+CD,banana
```

In such cases you need more complicated regular expressions or other tools (like `awk`).

Answer (score 1):

While You will get answer here, you should have a look at **[man grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)** (can be overwhelming) and [some examples](https://www.tecmint.com/12-practical-examples-of-linux-grep-command/). For the time being, here goes the answer :

#### Using `grep`

```
grep "foobar" test.txt
```

will search for lines having word `foobar` in file `test.txt` and display all occurrences whereas ,

```
grep "foo" -v "bar" test.txt
```

will search for lines having word `foo` but not `bar`. We get this because of **`-v`** switch for which manpage explains :

```
-v, --invert-match
    Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
    (-v is specified by POSIX .)
```

It simply means that It will search for lines having those words ( here `bar` ), but will exclude them in final display. Thus **[inverting the search](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/grep-how-reverse-invert-meaning-search)**.

Also, To count number of lines that matches the search, use **`-c`** switch :

```
-c, --count
    Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching lines
    for each input file. With the -v, --invert-match option (see below),
    count non-matching lines. (-c is specified by POSIX .)
```

As a self-exercise, try your hands upon grep search on file [foobar](https://ghostbin.com/paste/jn777).

#### The Answer

Search for `AB+CD` ignoring `nonAB` and `nonCD` and count URLs :

```
grep "AB+CD" test | grep -cve "non"
```

where `-v "non"` will simply ignore both `nonAB` and `nonCD` as they both have `non` in them. And `-c` will give total count for the matches instead of printing them. To print matching lines, just ignore `-c`.

You may use it for separate inverts :

```
grep "AB+CD" test | grep -cve "nonAB\|nonCD"
```

where `\|` represents `OR` and means either of `nonAB` or `nonCD` **exact** word specified by **`-e`** switch.

---

Would advise you to [see Kamil's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1329561/814740), read manpages (you know the command) as much you can, try hard while searching stuffs online & serve the community. Feel free to add-in more details to answer.